# Showing multiple errors in a div in jquery

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I want to display multiple form validation errors in a div and wants to stop the form being submit. Here is my code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Register</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#register").validate({
    //cusInvalid: false,
                    //by default validation will run on input keyup and focusout
                    //set this to false to validate on submit only
                    onkeyup: false,
                    onfocusout: false,
                    //by default the error elements is a <label>
                    errorElement: "div",
                      errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                        error.appendTo("div#error");
                    }, 
                    rules: {
                         user_name: "required",
           // lastname: "required",
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            },
          // agree: "required"
        },

         messages: {
            user_name: "Please enter your first name",
           // lastname: "Please enter your last name",
            password: {
                required: "Please provide a password",
                minlength: "Your password must be at least 5 characters long"
            },
            email: "Please enter a valid email address"
            //agree: "Please accept our policy"
        },

/*messages: {
     user_name: "Please specify your name.",
     email: {
       required: "We need your email address to contact you.",
       email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com"
     },
     password: "Please Enter Your Password",
     confirm_pass: "Please Enter Your Password Again"
   },
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
        if(errorList.length) {
            $("#error").html(errorList[0].message);
        }
    }*/
});
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div style="color:#FFF; background-color:#F00;" id="error" class="error"></div>
<?php $name='';$email='';$password='';$confirm_pass='';?>
<form name="register" method="post"id="register" class="register">
<div style="">Username:</div>
<div style=""><input type="text" name="user_name" id="user_name" class="user_name"></div>
<div style="">Email:</div>
<div style=""><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="email"></div>
<div style="">Password:</div>
<div style=""><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="password"></div>
<div style="">Password Again:</div>
<div style=""><input type="text" name="confirm_pass" id="confirm_pass" class="confirm_pass"></div>  
<div style="" id="pass_strenght">Strength Indicator:</div>
<div style=""><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></div>  
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PLease tell me what am I doing wrong. Your relpies are mostly welcome. And also I want to ask a question write now I am working in CI(codeIgniter). So please tell me where should i have to place jquery.min file...on the root or somewhere else. In this I made a js folder and put my jquery.min file in that on the root. And also tell me how sholuld I include the file in src attribute? Have i done right???

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
```

Comment: I think you need jquery.validate plugin to use the `validate()` method

Comment: @Oliboy50 I have added jquery.validate plugin but it stills not working. can u pls tell me the jquery files which is required to run the script..Give me a link so that I can download k

Comment: Next time please indicate the specific multiple errors that you've encountered. :)

Comment: @Cary Bondoc Actually I am new to Jquery and My script was not showing any error at that time. But thanks I solved the problem :-)

Comment: Now I know @xxxy2j, thanks! :) I'm glad you fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use [jQuery validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) but have not included the script in your header.

The easiest method is simply to include the script from CDN:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery.Validate/1.6/jQuery.Validate.min.js"></script>
```

Which should solve your problem.

Comment: I have included validate plugin but its still not working...Is there any other way to validate the form in Jquery without using the Jquery validate plugin?? if yes pls share with me anyone. thanks

Comment: can u pls tell me if my jquery code is correct or not. Actually I am new to jquery

Comment: There are one or two problems with your code. The major one being that you can't have a `<script>` tag with *both* a `src` AND content. You have to have two separate tags. So the bit where you are bringing in the minified jQuery is fine BUT you need to then close that `<script>` tag and begin another before entering your own code.

Comment: The second thing I can see after a quick read though is that you are loading the jQuery validator script AFTER jQuery itself - some scripts get really picky about this. I would swap the order.